# How do I reduce the minimum width of a Button on a ButtonBar in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have created a spark ButtonBar which is dynamically populated with XML and skinned to look like a standard TabBar.

When I used the TabBar in Flex 3, the width of each Tab would shrink or grow to the size of the Label, plus a little padding either side.

When using the spark ButtonBar in Flex 4, I find that no matter how short the label (even an empty string), the Buttons will be at least 70 pixels wide, and will expand for longer labels.

I have tried setting the minWidth to 20 in various places, including on my ButtonBarButton skin, but this has no effect.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create both a custom ButtonBarSkin as well as ButtonBarButtonSkin(s).  The default ButtonBarSkin uses three different ButtonBarButtonSkins:

1. ButtonBarFirstButtonSkin
2. ButtonBarMiddleButtonSkin
3. ButtonBarLastButtonSkin

These skins are your culprits.  (1) and (3) both have a `<s:Rect id="shadow"... width="69"...>` as the bottom-most layer.  The middle one has a border Rect with a width of 69, this time on the upper-most layer.  Remove those elements and you can make the minWidth in the skins whatever you'd like. :)

Comment: Hi Merv,Thanks for that.... set me on the path to get the solution within 15 minutes (after spending about 4 hours on the problem!).

Comment: I was using my own ButtonBarButtonSkins created in Flash Catalyst (awsome product by the way). However, the path creating the outline of the button had coordinates which extended to an x value slightly above 70. So while the buttons were expanding beyond this value, they weren't contracting. Your response enabled me to narrow it down to this very quickly. So THANKYOU! Cheers,Ben

Comment: Glad to help.  I'm guessing since you were using Flash Catalyst (agreed on the usefulness, btw) for the skins, yours were probably using the spark.skins.wireframe templates, instead of the spark.skins.spark templates that I was basing my post on.

Comment: Correct! With FLEX 4 (once we finally our app to compile!) and Flash Catalyst, we were able to take the look of our app to a whole new level within a day.